# Eclipse not running app on android phone

Tags: android, eclipse

I have been using my HTC One M8 to test my apps in the Android Eclipse IDE but recently it has stopped working. The phone shows up in the DDMS and the console says that it is installed on the phone but I can't find the application anywhere.
I am on a Mac if that helps at all.

Comment: anything in log cat?

Comment: hehe! try restarting your device.

Comment: When I hit run, this showed up in the logcat `12-05 10:23:32.915: W/HtcNativeFlag(20648): Fail to get flag string for type 'customer', use default value
12-05 10:23:32.915: W/HtcNativeFlag(20648): Fail to get flag for type 'customer', use default value: -1
12-05 10:23:32.915: W/HtcNativeFlag(20648): Fail to get flag string for type 'language', use default value
12-05 10:23:32.915: W/HtcNativeFlag(20648): Fail to get flag for type 'language', use default value: -1`

Comment: It looks like the console says that the is "No launcher activity found"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it appear in the Application manager?

If yes, the following once did work for me, since i forgot to define the Main Activity as following in the Manifest.xml:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

These lines made my app "launchable" for me.